# How do I make my react dropzone uploader accessible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, uploader

Issue : I am using the [react-dropzone-uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/) in my form. All my inputs are accessible except for the dropzone which I can't tab too or open without a mouse. Does anyone know a hack or a prop that I am missing? I've checked the docs but can't see anything about accessibility.

My code:

```
<div className="form-input--dropzone-uploader">
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="profileImage"
    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => {
      return (
        <Uploader
          onFileChange={(files) => onChange(files[0])}
          accept="image/*"
          inputContent={'Click or Drag to Upload Profile Picture'}
          multiple={false}
          maxFiles={1}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Having glanced at the [react-dropzone-uploader page](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/) it certainly does seem as though it is lacking any out-of-the-box accessibility...